# Node Minor Code Issues - Require and Exported Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, require

In a Previous Commit:

- We Call A Function like So `var previousRoute = appRouter.getPreviousRoute();`
- Where appRouter is `var appRouter = require("app_utilities/default/app-router");`
- and app-router contains an export as the following:

```
module.exports = {
   getPreviousRoute: getPreviousRoute
}

function getPreviousRoute() {
   return window.appPreviousRoute;
};
```

however in a latter commit the following line errors:

`var previousRoute = appRouter.getPreviousRoute();`

The **Error** would be: `Uncaught TypeError: appRouter.getPreviousRoute is not a function`

and we have to change it to:
`var previousRoute = appRouter.getPreviousRoute;`

I would like to know what would make it that we would need to drop the parentheses?

I have ran:

- `node -p process.versions.v8`

  - `6.8.275.32-node.36`

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely as you have declared a variable not the ***type function*** to export and the variable inside export holds the reference of the function so if you directly access `getPreviousRoute` a function it will produce an error as you did not export a function and the program will not find that. So in terms of working when a variable is called the program will find that its declared then will look for its reference function that you gave and will execute it

Instead if you will export like

```
exports.getPreviousRoute = ()=>{}
```

It will not show you an error as its a type of function and will be accessible let me also point if i am wrong